# Tumblr photoset's iframe loading 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-status-code-404, tumblr

I haven't found anyone with this problem either in stackoverflow or anywhere else and Tumblr support is being obtuse.

A few photosets on my tumblr are mysteriously loading a 404 not found page within the photoset iframe. When I view the source and click on the content link for that photoset, I can load it. Right now it is happening to the second post down on http://margodunlap.com/tagged/parsonssproutlogo, but earlier that post was fine and a different photoset on a different page was 404-ing. That photoset cleared up.

If it's useful, here is the code from the problem component/post:

```
<div id="photoset_31450068393" class="html_photoset">    <iframe class="photoset" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="458" width="500"
            style="border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" src="http://margodunlap.com/post/31450068393/photoset_iframe/margodunlap/tumblr_ma9xxmCe2n1rdhvsg/500/false"></iframe></div>
```

My instinct is that this is tumblr's servers messing up but is it possible it is a problem with my photoset script? It is below - I believe it is a common one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".photoset").each(function() {
$(this).width('800px');
var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace('500','800');
$(this).attr("src", newSrc);
});


$(function(){
var iFrames = $('.photoset');

function iResize() {
for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
    iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
}

if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 
    iFrames.load(function(){
        setTimeout(iResize, 0); 
    });

    for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
        var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
        iFrames[i].src = '';
        iFrames[i].src = iSource;
    }
} else {
    iFrames.load(function() {
        this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    });
}
});
});
```

Also I don't know if this is relevant but Chrome's java console is telling me that a few other scripts on the page (tumblr's marketing trackers and my google analytics) are failing to load. Please know I'm a designer, not a programmer, and I'm trying my best for this to not be a dumb question. Basically I've spent six months tweaking this website, my portfolio, to be perfect and 12 hours before I was set to submit it as my grad school application, it does this. Huge lesson learned about hosting important things in reliable places but in the meantime please help if you can, I'm desperate and sad.

I've taken the problem post down because of the whole submitting to grad school thing, but if anyone knows what the problem with this might be I'd really appreciate a permanent fix.